# CSS/HTML Flowchart

Tags: html, css

I need a very simple, straightforward CSS/HTML flowchart in the format below:

```
Node1
  |
Node2
  |
Node3
  |
Node4
  |
Node5
  |
Node6
```

I know next to nothing about CSS but attempted to modify the one detailed in the link below. The Problem was I only want a linear, vertical chart and it ended up all over the place!

http://www.htmlforums.com/css/t-flowchart-using-css-85999.html

Can anyone help?

Comment: HTML is not designed to be a diagramming language. I'd switch to use SVG instead.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I could utilise SVG to create the flowchart then add HTML or jQuery elements to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this is works for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/wkCNm/

---

In case the JS Fiddle disappears, here is the code.

**HTML**

```
<h1>A simple family tree using 32 divs</h1>

<div id="container">

<div id="no1"><a href="#">Production Director</a></div>
<div id="line1"></div>
<div id="no1"><a href="#">Production Director</a></div>
<div id="line1"></div>
<div id="no1"><a href="#">Production Director</a></div>
<div id="line1"></div>
<div id="no1"><a href="#">Production Director</a></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    width:580px;
    font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:40px auto;
}
#container {
    width:580px;
    font-family:verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}
#container a {
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#f6f6ff;
}
#container a:hover {
    color:#900;
    background-color:#f6f6ff;
}
#no1 {
    width:190px;
    line-height:60px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:auto;
}
#no1 a {
    height:60px;
}
#line1 {
    font-size:0;
    width:1px;
    height:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:auto;
}
#line2 {
    font-size:0;
    width:424px;
    height:1px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:auto;
}
#line3 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:1px;
    height:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:78px;
    float:left;
}
#line4,#line5,#line6 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:1px;
    height:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:140px;
    float:left;
}
#no2 {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid #000;
    clear:both;
    margin-left:35px;
    float:left;
}
#no2 a,#no4 a,#no8 a {
    width:84px;
    height:50px;
    padding-top:8px;
}
#no3 {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:58px;
    float:left;
}
#no3 a,#no5 a,#no6 a,#no7 a,#no9 a {
    width:84px;
    height:42px;
    padding-top:16px;
}
#no4 {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:53px;
    float:left;
}
#no5 {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:55px;
    float:left;
}
#line7,#line13 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:1px;
    height:38px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:219px;
    float:left;
}
#line8,#line14 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:1px;
    height:38px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-left:281px;
    float:left;
}
#no6,#no8 {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:107px;
    float:left;
}
#line9,#line11,#line15,#line17 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:26px;
    height:1px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin-top:29px;
    float:left;
}
#line10,#line12,#line16,#line18 {
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;
    width:1px;
    height:60px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
}
#line16,#line18 {
    height:30px;
}
#no7,#no9 {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:169px;
    float:left;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: That's looking great! If I was to add unlimited additional nodes, how would I do that?

Comment: @Frap If you use some sort of loop to render all your flowchart items, you could tell it to render the line1 div after each element to make it look like that.

Comment: To add more, just duplicate the following:

<pre>
<div id="line1"></div>
<div id="no1"><a href="#">Production Director</a></div>
</pre>

Comment: @Frap, I forgot to mention. Make the ID's into classes, As what its current will not validate. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So instead of div id, change it to div class and then change the css to . instead of #?

Comment: looks like this came from http://www.htmlforums.com/css/t-flowchart-using-css-85999.html ........ if anyone is interested (I know it's not the answer to the question, but additional useful info) then this source has extra nodes/siblings http://jsfiddle.net/pointbypointuk/ETg7q/2/